# Random questions from database to display randomly on button click index.html page

Tags: php, mysql

i am pretty new to PHP and database implementation to websites. I am currently trying to make a website with PHP and HTML that fetches questions stored in a table in a database. I have manage to get the questions from the database to print to the screen when the page is refreshed, but i am struggeling to make one at the time pop up in a random order when a button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SQL SPORSMÅL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testphpquestions.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Random Data from Database</h1>
    <?php if (isset($randomRow)): ?>
        <p><?php echo $randomRow['question']; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="random">Get Random Data</button>
    </form>

    <?php        
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my username', 'my password', 'Databasename');
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    
        // Retrieve data from database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $rows = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }
    
        // Close database connection
        $conn->close();
    
        // Handle button click
        if (isset($_POST['random'])) {
            // Select a random row
            $randomIndex = array_rand($rows);
            $randomRow = $rows[$randomIndex];
        }
    
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have googled and tried to ask CHATGPT without sucsess

Answer (score 1):

By changing your query you can have a random row to fetch from DB

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"
```